# SQL Query to select the name of the branch with max number of employees working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I made a database that have table named Employee and table named Branch, there is a many to one relationship between Employee and Branch and i want to make a query to select the branch that have the max number of employees working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT TOP 1 BranchId, COUNT(*) FROM Employee
 GROUP BY BranchId
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This gets you the BranchId with the most number of employees - you can then use this as part of other queries to get the information you require.

Comment: its true but if we have more that one branch with same max of count(*) ? you always get the top of branch id ,

Answer (score 1):

Having a column called branchID in table Employee and in table branch, you can do:

To get the branchID with most Employees:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 branchID
 FROM employee
 GROUP BY branchID
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Then to get all the information from branch table:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM branch b
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT TOP 1 branchID
 FROM employee
 GROUP BY branchID
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) c ON b.branchID = c.branchID;
```